# Entire app reload on redux state change. (React native)

Tags: react-native, redux, expo

I don't know if this is the right place for this.  but yeah I am facing this problem with my react native expo app. it's an e-commerce app. initially, I am fetching user cart items and storing them in the redux state. and when the user proceeds to add a new item to the cart. I then call an API to add and retrieve the new cart items and update the redux state with the new set of records.  now the problem is. this reloads the entire app. and returns back to the home screen.

I don't know why it's doing that anyway. I was wondering if there is a way I could stop this redirecting?

UPDATE::::
I just noticed that it does the same on the home screen when trying to update the redux. it keeps refreshing.

Function to get items from the cart

```js
async getCartItems(){
    this.setState({
        refreshing:true
    })
    const  buyer_id = this.props.data?.userRecords?.id;
    globalFunctions.getSecureValue(my_user_token) //geting token from the securestorage
      .then((response) =>{

          if (response) {
              vendorServices.getItemCart(buyer_id,response) //getting the user cart items
                .then((data) =>{
                    if (data) {
                        this.props.addCartCount(data.data.length); //updating the redux state for cart counter
                        this.props.addToCart(data.data);  //updating the redux state for cart items records
                        if(this._ismounted){
                            this.setState({
                                refreshing:false
                            })
                        }
                    }

                })
                .catch((error) =>{
                    console.log(error)
                })
          }

      })
}
```

The main point here is that. why does the entire app have to reload on the redux state change?  is there a way I can stop this?
Please help.

Comment: Can you edit the question so it shows the code where the problem is occurring?

Comment: updated. please check. and yeah my main point is. I want to stop the app from reloading  when the redux state change.

Comment: could it be that you are mutating the full state of the app, so thats why is reloading?

Comment: it could be so and how do stop directly mutating please.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved it. happen that I was calling the redux function in the parent component. even though I was not using it, it always run it and cause the app to remount every time the state change